# Using a server to supply a content feed android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I currently have an application on Google play which I want to add in-app purchases.
I have a few questions that I was wondering about:
 1. Is there a preferred obfuscation tool? The one recommended on android's developer help is called ProGuard, but I was wondering if there is a better one. 
 2. I am more of a client-side developer, I don't really like getting into server-side, I consider it my weaker point. One of the security practices recommended on android developer help is to use a remote server to supply a content feed into the phone with the content.
I am unclear on what I need to do on my side to do this. Do I need to make a server to act as the content supplier?
 3. I am looking to create a currency in my game, and using the in-app billing as a means to get this currency, for A price you get B amount of currency. How do I secure the values of the currency? Do I put them on a server database and secure it there? or do I place them in the device and encrypt the value?

I am sorry if this seems messy, unorganized, or otherwise broad or incomplete, I have looked everywhere I could for the answers to these questions, but I couldn't seem to find them, even now I am looking at the similar questions on the right hand side and couldn't find an answer.
Thank you very much to those of you who will answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK, ProGuard is good tool for obfuscation, you have to be careful while obfuscating, since ProGuard not just obfuscates, but also shrinks which means unnecessary code will be removed. While adding 3rd party libs, you need to add few more lines to proguard.cfg or proguard.txt as recommended by them.
2. Yes you should.
3. Since you have mentioned **game** hope it works offline, so you have left with only one option store locally. Yes you should also secure with your own **SALT** to retrieve the values back. I do it to secure my APIs.

However doing all above will definitely reduce the risk of your app being misused, but hackers always find a way to break through it.